# mac ports 32/64 bit error

Tags: macos, macports

I'm consistently getting errors across the board related to the following problem, on Mac osx 10.7.4 via a 2011 mac book pro.

these errors are mostly from mathematical related dev libs that compile and run example code without error on various linux machines, while using similar make files

the error i get is usually something on the lines of

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

this also occurs with various compilers and no matter how i compile the lib I link, clang, various versions of gcc even haskell's ghc

some libs that give me errors are

- PETSC(which i compiled from source and none of the examples compile
  with make test)
- GSL(from macports) gives same error
- FFTW... and the list goes on

I believe the culprit  is that some where along the line something (maybe a compiler) was compiled via macports improperly,

for instance `gcc -v` states it was compiled `Target: i686-apple-darwin11`

```
--build=i686-apple-darwin11 --enable-llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~28/dst-llvmCore/Developer/usr/local --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11
```

while every other compiler, clang , g++-mp-4.7 exc,  says Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11

is there any solution to this problem?

is there a way to recompile everything enforcing 64 bit? Would that fix the above problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac OS X has its own build toolchain, so this probably is a path issue.

Check

```
which gcc
```

and compare the path with any library you know comes from mac ports (probably in /opt/bin).

As a solution, putting the /opt/bin path at the beginning of your $PATH should work out.

Comment: `which gcc`  gives `/usr/bin/gcc`

Comment: Ups, that article was for developing packages. sorry.

Comment: It's already in the front heres the what `$PATH` generates `/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:`